# Expand collapse issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change font awesome '+' icon to '-' icon when list is expanded could any one help me.

jQuery:

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$ul.find('li[Catparent-id]').each(function() {
  $ul.find('li[Catparent-id=' + $(this).attr('Catli-id') + ']').wrapAll('<ul />').parent().appendTo(this)
});

var $expandBtns = $('.expandBtn');
var $span;

//counting childs 

$expandBtns.each(function() {
  $span = $(this).find('span#count');
  var $subList = $(this).siblings('ul').find('li')
  if ($subList.length > 0) {
    $span.append(' ' + $subList.length);
  } else {
    $span.css('display', 'none');
  }
});

//Collapse and Expand
$('#orgCat ul').hide('li');
$expandBtns.on('click', function() {
  var $subList = $(this).siblings('ul');
  $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').find('ul').hide('slow');
  if ($subList.is(':visible')) {
    $subList.hide('slow');
  } else {
    $subList.show('slow');
  }
});
```

For HTML and CSS [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zu8m1nab/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need

```
var plusClass = "fa-plus-circle";
var minusClass = "fa-minus-circle";
//Collapse and Expand
$('#orgCat ul').hide('li');
$expandBtns.on('click', function() {
    var $subList = $(this).siblings('ul');
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').find('ul').hide('slow');       
    //reset icons since you close other children 
    $(this).parent('li').siblings('li').find('i').
        removeClass(minusClass).addClass(plusClass);
    if ($subList.is(':visible')) {
        $subList.hide('slow');
        $(this).find("i:first").addClass(plusClass).removeClass(minusClass);
        $(this).removeClass("blue");
    } else {
        $subList.show('slow');
        $(this).find("i:first").removeClass(plusClass).addClass(minusClass);
        $(this).addClass("blue");
   }
});
```

Fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/8aaq0j4c/2/

Fiddle with color change ==> https://jsfiddle.net/8aaq0j4c/3/

Comment: Done Thank you. how to change that parent font  color when expanded

Comment: Which one? The one with the icon?

Comment: issue is there. expand INDIA ==> TS and now expand TN icon '-' is not changed

Comment: Wait I'm forking your fiddle

Comment: or simply expand india first then click on usa you may observe the icon

Comment: Done @TonySamperi, Thank you and Text color??

Comment: Color thing done! Now I'll do some refactor to see if code can be improved

Comment: color issue: onclick the color is applying. Requirement is color should apply to only expanded parent 'LI'

Comment: so if you expand a child it should stay black?

Comment: Yes for example, I expanded INDIA ==> TN then blue should apply to INDIA and TN remaining parents black only

Comment: No I'm having lunch...give me half an hour!

Comment: there is an issue in answer. Issue: expand India -> TN now collapse India then expand it. Child list of TN is not collapsed observe it. https://jsfiddle.net/8aaq0j4c/

Comment: You know that stack overflow is not a place where programmers work for you for free, right? I gave you a hint, now you should learn how to collapse the children.